Return duplicate rows from a table
I have a table which contains invalid duplicate records and I am trying to find the same. The below is the query, which returns the result.
SELECT Id,
       StartDate,
       EndDate,
       Rate,
       TDate,
       COUNT(*) AS Record
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Id,
         StartDate,
         EndDate,
         Rate,
         TDate
HAVING COUNT(*)>1

Now, there is a requirement. One of the Rate is 'NP', which is correctly supposed to have duplicates. It only becomes an invalid/incorrect if a duplicate 'NP' record is accompanied by any other duplicated Rate 'X' for the same ID and TDate.
How do I go about finding the same? After going through the comments, I realize I'm not able to explain fully what the issue Im facing is. The time part is necessary to get the duplicates, meaning, it's not a duplicate of the time is different even though the TDate is the same, hence why I grouped by both startdate and enddate in my query. Example Id 4 has 3 data of Rate X, but only 1 of them is duplicated.



Id
StartDate
EndDate
Rate
Tdate




1
19-06-2024 12:00
19-06-2024 14:00
NP
19-06-2024


1
19-06-2024 12:00
19-06-2024 14:00
NP
19-06-2024


2
17-06-2024 12:00
17-06-2024 14:00
NP
17-06-2024


2
17-06-2024 12:00
17-06-2024 14:00
NP
17-06-2024


2
17-06-2024 14:00
17-06-2024 16:00
P
17-06-2024


2
17-06-2024 14:00
17-06-2024 16:00
P
17-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 12:00
16-06-2024 14:00
NP
16-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 12:00
16-06-2024 14:00
NP
16-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 10:00
16-06-2024 12:00
P
16-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 10:00
16-06-2024 12:00
P
16-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 08:00
16-06-2024 10:00
X
16-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 08:00
16-06-2024 10:00
X
16-06-2024


4
15-06-2024 08:00
15-06-2024 10:00
P
15-06-2024


4
15-06-2024 08:00
15-06-2024 10:00
P
15-06-2024


4
15-06-2024 12:00
15-06-2024 14:00
X
15-06-2024


4
15-06-2024 12:00
15-06-2024 14:00
X
15-06-2024


4
15-06-2024 15:00
15-06-2024 16:00
X
15-06-2024



Here, we can see that Id 1 is duplicated with Rate NP. But for the same TDate and Id, 1 does not have any other duplicated data of Rate X. Hence this is a valid record.
Id 2, has two duplicates of rate NP along with another duplicate of Rate P. So the duplicated rate P, is invalid. But duplicated rate NP, is valid since it is not accompanied by Rate X.
For Id 3, it has duplicates of NP, P and X. Thus for this Id 3, it should return all 3 as invalid.
Id 4, has two duplicates of Rate P and X, so both are invalid.
So from the data above, I am expecting results as:



Id
StartDate
EndDate
Rate
Tdate




2
17-06-2024 14:00
17-06-2024 16:00
P
17-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 12:00
16-06-2024 14:00
NP
16-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 10:00
16-06-2024 12:00
P
16-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 08:00
16-06-2024 10:00
X
16-06-2024


4
15-06-2024 08:00
15-06-2024 10:00
P
15-06-2024


4
15-06-2024 12:00
15-06-2024 14:00
X
15-06-2024




You seem to ignore the time parts of your dates when grouping, is that intentional or not?

The StartDate and EndDate seem to be extra columns that are not part of the duplicate logic. Its only Tdate that is checked and it has no time.

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/KhcbHCyl

@BartMcEndree, It's the first time I am seeing that site. This will help me tremendously in the future. Thank you

your logic is unclear.

Will all records for a given Id value always have the same Tdate value, as per your example? Or could there be a vairety of Tdate values for the same Id? Equally, will there always be pairs of records for the same Rate within each Id, or could there be a single record for a given Id and Rate?

Furthermore, is there always an "NP" Rate for a given Id and if not, how should an Id with only non-NP Rates be handled? Overall I agree with the previous commentor, the logic you desire is unclear. It would be easy to write a query which gives the result you show in your example, but it feels like there are lots of other data states you've not explained, or specified that they will not arise.

TDate is just the StartDate and EndDate's Date only value which is based off on StartDate. It is not necessary for all Ids to have compulsory NP rates. They can have only X or P as well, in that case , if there are any duplicates, count as invalid.

Here is one solution using a common table expression (CTE) to perform the grouping 1 time and self join on the results.
--Duplicated records (exclude records with NP rates unless X rate duplicates in same group)
WITH RecordsWithDuplicates as
( 
  --Duplicated records
  SELECT Id, StartDate, EndDate, Rate, Tdate
  FROM  Example
  GROUP BY ID, Tdate,  StartDate, EndDate, Rate
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT d.id, FORMAT(d.StartDate,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') as StartDate, FORMAT(d.EndDate,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') as EndDate,  d.Rate, FORMAT(d.Tdate,'dd-MM-yyyy') as Tdate
FROM RecordsWithDuplicates d
LEFT JOIN RecordsWithDuplicates x on x.id=d.id and x.TDate=d.Tdate and x.Rate='X'
WHERE d.Rate!='NP' OR (d.Rate='NP' AND x.id IS NOT NULL)

fiddle



Id
StartDate
EndDate
Rate
Tdate




2
17-06-2024 14:00
17-06-2024 16:00
P
17-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 12:00
16-06-2024 14:00
NP
16-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 10:00
16-06-2024 12:00
P
16-06-2024


3
16-06-2024 08:00
16-06-2024 10:00
X
16-06-2024


4
15-06-2024 08:00
15-06-2024 10:00
P
15-06-2024


4
15-06-2024 12:00
15-06-2024 14:00
X
15-06-2024




Thank you so much, Bart. Really appreciate it. I have made some edits to the question as the Start Date and EndDate should be part of the duplicate logic as I have explained in the edit. But I feel like I can work towards the solution from the idea that you have given.

@Laba Ningombam I have updated the fiddle and my returned results to match your edit. I still do not see any examples that change the query or the results I get.

@Laba Ningombam Query updated to include Start and end dates in grouping

You just need to see if there are any non-NP rows over the common "rate set" (not sure if you have a better name.)
with dups as (
    SELECT 
        Id, StartDate, EndDate,
        Rate, TDate, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount,
        count(case when Rate <> 'NP' then 1 end)
            over (Id, StartDate, EndDate, TDate) as NonNPCount
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY 
        Id, StartDate, EndDate, Rate, TDate
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
select * from dups
where Rate <> 'NP' or NonNPCount > 0;

